# Java Regex matching Groups, why does the first groups encompass whole expression?

Tags: java, regex

I want to understand how the group function in java regex works.

When I use the regex

```
([\u25CB\u25CF])\s+([\u25CB\u25CF])\s+([\u25CB\u25CF])\s+([\u25CB\u25CF])\s+
```

on the Text

```
Prozesse & Methoden
Technische Dokumentation    ○   ○   ●   ○
OSI Model   ○   ○   ●   ○
```

I would expect to have first match look like this: groups 0 to 3 like "○", "○", "●", "○".
Four groups with one circle in it.

But in fact it looks like this: "○ ○ ● ○", "○", "○", "●". The groups () only span one character each, how can the first group encompass the whole expression?

When I add an empty group behind my expression it matches like this:

```
([\u25CB\u25CF])\s+([\u25CB\u25CF])\s+([\u25CB\u25CF])\s+([\u25CB\u25CF])\s+()
```

"○ ○ ● ○", "○", "○", "●", "○"

The last non empty group is remembered then. I can not understand why.

Tested both with java 1.8 and on website http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: Group zero encompasses the entire pattern. So, for the four bubbles you'll have to use group(1) to group(4).

Comment: Your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/iklBaw/) is working as expected, each group matches 1 "circle". However the group 0 returns the whole matched string.